# Современные обращения друг к другу

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Прошу помощи. Как правильно нужно обращаться к человеку в письме. Например: "Лен!" или "Лена!". Возник спор. Я считаю, что обращение "Лен!" как-то неуважительно. Как Вы считаете?

Answer (score 4):

Выбор обращения зависит от того, в каких отношениях находятся автор письма и адресат. Также не менее важную роль играют предпочтения: нравится ли человеку, когда к нему обращаются "Лен!", "Лена!" и т. д. или нет.

Форма *Лен!* краткая и уместна скорее в разговоре друзей, хороших знакомых, нежели в деловом письме. Ничего неуважительного в таком обращении нет, однако нужно понимать, где и когда стоит его употреблять.

Answer (score 2):

В разговорной речи краткое обращение "Лен", "Серёж" и т. п. часто встречается и допустимо, но в письме лучше и вежливее называть человека без разговорного сокращения: "Лена", "Серёжа" и т. п.